# jQuery in Yii2 view file

Tags: jquery, yii2

This is my form code:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'stdclass_id')->dropDownList($stdclassArray,
    ['prompt' => 'Select','id' => 'selectedclass'])->label('Class') ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'session_id')->dropDownList($sessionArray,
    ['prompt' => 'Select', 'id' => 'selectedsession',])->label('Session') ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'roll_no')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'id' => 'roll']) ?>
```

And this is the jQuery part of the form:

```
$script = <<< JS

$('#selectedsession').on('change',function(){
    var value1 = document.getElementById("selectedclass").value;
    var value2 = document.getElementById("selectedsession").value;

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo Yii::$app->request->baseUrl. '/enrollment/rollno' ?>',
        type: "POST",
        data: { value1: value1, value2 : value2 },
        success: function(data) {
            var abc = data;
            $("#roll").val(abc);
        }
    });
});

JS;
```

This produces the following error:

> Undefined Variable: app

I'm not able to use `yii::$app`.

Comment: I also included use yii\helpers\Url;

Answer (score 2):

Extract php variables from here doc.

```
$baseUrl = Yii::$app->request->baseUrl;

$script = <<< JS

$('#selectedsession').on('change',function(){
var value1 = document.getElementById("selectedclass").value;
var value2 = document.getElementById("selectedsession").value;

$.ajax({

             url: '{$baseUrl}/enrollment/rollno',
             type: "POST",
             data: { value1: value1, value2 : value2 },
             success: function(data) {
                 var abc = data;
                $("#roll").val(abc);
             }
         });
});

JS;
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. You made my day :)